# How to create a radio button dynamically with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a small application in which I want to create 20 radio buttons in one row.

How can I do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think this will serve your purpose:

```js
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var radioBtn = $('<input type="radio" name="rbtnCount" />');
    radioBtn.appendTo('#target');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Answer (score 12):

You can do it with [appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/), within a for loop:

```js
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    $('<input type="radio" name="dynradio" />').appendTo('.your_container');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="your_container"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Something along the lines of:

```js
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    $('#element').append('<input type="radio" name="radio_name" />');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    $('<input type="radio" name="radiobtn" >Yourtext'+i+'</input>').appendTo('#container');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This code will append radio buttons with unique id to each of them....

```
for (var i=0;i<=20;i++)
{
 $("#yourcontainer").append("<input type='radio' id='myRadio"+i+"'>")
}
```

Comment: They don’t have any name, they’re useless.

Answer (score 2):

You have to find the element that should contain your radio buttons and [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) them:

```js
var container = $('#radio_container');
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    container.append('<input type="radio" name="radio_group" value="' + i + '">');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="radio_container">Choose one: </div>
```

Thus you search for the container only once (unlike in the other answers) and assign a value to each radio that lets you identify the choice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a div with the ID=myDivContainer
try this:

```
for (i=0;i<=20;i++)
{
$("#myDivContainer").append('<input type="radio" />')
}
```

Comment: The input doesn’t have all the required attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=0;i<=20;i++)
  {
  $("#yourcontainer").append("<input type='radio' name='myRadio' />");
  }
```