# How to insert a checkbox in a list in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to create a todo list with JS. The idea is to write something in the input and when the user clicks the button, he obtains a checkbox with the text on it.

The problem is that I don't know how can I do it with JS. I tried to change the 'li' to an input and then setAttribute("type", "checkbox"), but nothing happened.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lista de tareas personal.</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
        }
        li{
            width: 50%;
            list-style-type: none;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Lista de tareas personal.</h1>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="añadirItems">Añadir Item</button>
    <input type="text" id="texto">

    <!---<ul id="lista"> </ul>-->
    <ul id="ul"> </ul>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       function addItem(){
           var ul = document.getElementById('ul'); //ul
           var li = document.createElement('li');//li
           var text = document.getElementById('texto');
           li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text.value));
           ul.appendChild(li);  
       }
       var button = document.getElementById('btn');
       button.onclick = addItem 
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use jQuery's [`$.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) method to convert your `<li>` to an `<input type="checkbox">`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't seem to use jquery, so the jquery tag wont get you helpful answers.
You can create a checkbox in the same way you created your li element.

```
function addItem(){
    var ul = document.getElementById('ul'); //ul
    var li = document.createElement('li');//li

    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        checkbox.value = 1;
        checkbox.name = "todo[]";

    li.appendChild(checkbox);

    var text = document.getElementById('texto');
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text.value));
    ul.appendChild(li); 
}

var button = document.getElementById('btn');
button.onclick = addItem;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u7f5rwjs/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamic checkbox like

```
$('#containerId').append('<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" />');
```

where **containerId** is the id of the DOM element you want to add the checkbox to.

Or alternative syntax...

```
$('#containerId')
    .append(
       $(document.createElement('input')).attr({
           id:    'myCheckbox'
          ,name:  'myCheckbox'
          ,value: 'myValue'
          ,type:  'checkbox'
       })
    );
```

For more information See the following link: [**create dynamically radio button in jquery**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550785/create-dynamically-radio-button-in-jquery/5551205#5551205)

Here it is showing how to create radio button using jQuery, you can change the code to create Checkbox.

**As per your requirement :**

```
function addItem(){
        var ul = document.getElementById('ul'); //ul
        var li = document.createElement('li');//li
        var text = document.getElementById('texto');
        li.appendChild( $(document.createElement('input')).attr({
               id:    'myCheckbox'
              ,name:  'myCheckbox'
              ,value: 'myValue'
              ,type:  'checkbox'
           }));
        ul.appendChild(li); 
}
    var button = document.getElementById('btn');
    button.onclick = addItem
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read this question: [Creating the checkbox dynamically using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866239/creating-the-checkbox-dynamically-using-javascript)

Just add the part of the checkbox in your code:

```
 function addItem(){
        var ul = document.getElementById('ul'); //ul
        var li = document.createElement('li');//li
        var text = document.getElementById('texto');

        var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        checkbox.name = "name";
        checkbox.value = "value";
        checkbox.id = "id";

        li.appendChild(checkbox);
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text.value));
        ul.appendChild(li); 
}
```

And the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8uwr3kpw/