# ASP.Net Survey & Radio Options from database

Tags: jquery, asp.net

We have about 10 questions & Options value information in a database. on click of a button, we would like to show 3 questions in a pop up, and after answering all the three questions, we should enable "Next" button. once all the questions are completed, we want to save that information back to the database and we are using asp.net 2013, javascript, jquery.

questions & options are dynamic from database, not sure how to dynamically generate radio options for each question and access them to save.

e.g. below...

[image: Question Pop Up]

Comment: You have enough rep to know you should research this yourself and try something first before asking for help.  What problem are you having? What have you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550785/how-to-create-a-radio-button-dynamically-with-jquery